# hover full width dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Please, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/2bU3R/3/

When I hover over the Magazine list, the first dropdown doesn't show.

I want it to work for many dropdowns.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#sub-menu-1').hover( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".sub-menu-1-open").slideDown("fast");
    });
    $('.sub-menu-1-open').mouseleave( function(){
        $('.sub-menu-1-open').slideUp("fast");
    });
    $('#sub-menu-2').hover( function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".sub-menu-2-open").slideDown("fast");
    });
    $('.sub-menu-2-open').mouseleave( function(){
        $('.sub-menu-2-open').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: please check my demo and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE #2**

If you keep the HTML markup the way it is now, this should work.

All the `jQuery (Javascript)` you need is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[class^='sub-menu'] .inner").mouseleave(function () {
        hideMenu();
    });

    $(".list-inline li a").mouseenter(function () {
        hideMenu();
        $("." + $(this).parent().attr("id") + "-open").stop().slideDown();
    });
});

var hideMenu = function () { 
    $("div[class^='sub-menu']").stop().slideUp();
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2bU3R/22/

Comment: I have one more problem. e.g. when hover sub-menu-2-open, sub-menu-2-open close and open again

Comment: You didn't mention on the question that the menu should stay open.

Comment: Menu must be open when hover a list

Comment: Check the answer now. Hope it's fine.

Comment: But, if you don't go down to the sub-menu and you mouse-left from "News" the menu stays open????

Comment: Yes, but to keep tweaking it here is not the intention. The OP got this question answered.

Comment: how can do this to close when mouse left?

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bU3R/5/)**

Use `slideToggle()`

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $('#sub-menu-1').hover( function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();        
            $(".sub-menu-1-open").slideToggle("fast");  


        });

        $('.sub-menu-1-open').mouseleave( function(){

            $('.sub-menu-1-open').slideToggle("fast");

        });

        $('#sub-menu-2').hover( function(event){

            event.stopPropagation();

            $(".sub-menu-2-open").slideToggle("fast");

        });

        $('.sub-menu-2-open').mouseleave( function(){

            $('.sub-menu-2-open').slideToggle("fast");

        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this make it somewhat  a liitlebit more dynamic : http://jsfiddle.net/2bU3R/12/

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.list-inline li').hover(function(){
        var div = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.'+div+'-open').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

This basically runs itselfs.

Comment: I have one more problem. e.g. when hover sub-menu-2-open, sub-menu-2-open close and open again.